# Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow on Android

Tags: android, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to create a TableView containing a TableViewSection (which includes a header image) and several rows (which each inlude a label, some images and a button).

In the iPhone-Simulator, it all works well, but on the Android-Emulator, it only displays the row label. Even the hasDetail-Argument is ignored. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Below a simplified versionof my code.

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        scrollable:true
});

var item_list = Array('foo', 'bar');

var logo = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    width:193,
    height:44,
    visible:true,
    backgroundImage:'../images/logo.png',
});

var headerView = Titanium.UI.createView({
    height:50,
    backgroundColor:'#960017'
});


var listSection = Titanium.UI.createTableViewSection({
    headerView:headerView, 
    height:165,

});

for (i=0; i < item_list.length; i++) {

var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
    color:'#ffffff',
    hasDetail: true
});

row_title = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text: 'Foo',
        left: 4,
        color: '#ffffff',
        width: 200

});

row_button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Button text',
    width: 100,
    height: 24,
    right: 2,
});


var row_images = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
       width: 60,
       height: 12,
       image: '../images/image.png'
});

row.add(row_title, row_images, row_button);

listSection.add(row);

}

headerView.add(logo);
tableView.setData([listSection]); 

win.add(tableView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
headerView:headerView
```

try the following

```
var headerView = Titanium.UI.createView({
    height:50,
    backgroundColor:'#960017'
});
tableView.headerView = headerView;
```